# Bind click event on fluent ribbon button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, fluent-ribbon

I want to try fluent ribbon control. That's why i have downloaded it and added to my wpf project. My xaml code is

```
<Fluent:RibbonWindow x:Class="Fluent.Sample.Foundation.Window"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"     
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
    xmlns:Fluent="clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"     
    Title="Fluent.Sample.Foundation" Width="800" Height="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >


    <Fluent:Ribbon>
        <!--Backstage-->
        <Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>
            <Fluent:Backstage></Fluent:Backstage>
        </Fluent:Ribbon.Menu>
        <!--Tabs-->
        <Fluent:RibbonTabItem Header="Tab">
            <Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Group">
                <Fluent:Button Name="buttonGreen" Header="Green" Icon="Images\Green.png" LargeIcon="Images\GreenLarge.png" Click="btnClick" />
                <Fluent:Button Name="buttonGray" Header="Grey" Icon="Images\Gray.png" LargeIcon="Images\GrayLarge.png" />
            </Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
        </Fluent:RibbonTabItem>
    </Fluent:Ribbon>

</Fluent:RibbonWindow>
```

I have added click event on fluent ribbon button like this.

```
Class MainWindow 
    Private Sub btnClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        MsgBox("test")
    End Sub
End Class
```

But i get this error.

```
Type 'Fluent.RibbonWindow' is not defined.
Type 'Fluent.Button' is not defined.
'btnClick' is not a member of 'TestRibbon.Fluent.Sample.Foundation.Window'.
```

when i change **Fluent.RibbonWindow** to **Global.Fluent.RibbonWindow** and same thing with **Fluent.Button** it works well and after some time it again show the same error and i can't understand why this error occurred **'btnClick' is not a member of 'TestRibbon.Fluent.Sample.Foundation.Window'.**

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the below to your Resources? Have a look at the walkthrough at https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon.

```
<Ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--Attach Default Fluent Control's Theme-->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Office2010/Silver.xaml" />
            <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/office2013/generic.xaml" />-->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                       
    </ResourceDictionary>        
</Ribbon:RibbonWindow.Resources>
```